# Modify layout to have a custom variable aspect ratio, or width never higher than height

Tags: swiftui

I created a small component using a `Text` and optionally an `Image`, inside an `HStack`. Then I apply `padding` and `clipping` using a `Capsule` shape.

Below you have the code and the results.

The problem I have is that I want to constraint the component in a way that the width is always equal or higher than its height. That is, a vertical capsule is not allowed, only an horizontal capsule or a circle.

I tried different approaches.
For example, measure the component size using Geometry reader. We can use the .measure modifier, which basically puts everything inside .background and applies a Geometry Reader, and moves the value up using Preference Keys.
https://swiftuirecipes.com/blog/getting-size-of-a-view-in-swiftui
But it does not work, looks like the HStack is returning zero, or causing issues.

In any case, I was told to avoid `GeometryReader` whenever possible.
What other approaches I could follow?

There must be a way playing with `.background` and `.layoutPriority`, butI don't know exactly how to do it.

Would be nice to have something like an `.aspectRatio` modifier where we can pass something like "1 or higher", but I have no idea about how to implement that.

Do you have any idea or suggestion? Thanks a lot.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Label(text: "2", showIcon: true)
            Label(text: "99+", showIcon: true)
            Label(text: "1", showIcon: false) // Case to fix
        }
    }
}

struct Label: View {

    let text: String
    let showIcon: Bool

    var body: some View {
            HStack {
                if showIcon {
                    Image(systemName: "bolt")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                }
                Text(text)
            }
            .padding(4)
            .background(Color.red)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a minimum width for the `HStack`. That should do the job:

```
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if showIcon {
                Image(systemName: "bolt")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
            }
            Text(text)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 20) // < here
        .padding(4)
        .background(Color.red)
        .clipShape(Capsule())
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Although that works in some cases, it will not work when the user changes the font size through dynamic font sizing. I was thinking about using a ZStack, adding a second copy of the element with aspect ration to 1, but in that case, I need to apply that only to one dimension, and layoutPriority works in both dimensions. Any other idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, yes you could add a second copy in a ZStack. I would go for some dummy text in clear, that would also change size on dynamic font sizing:

```
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                if showIcon {
                    Image(systemName: "bolt")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                }
                Text(text)
            }
            .padding(4)
            
            Text("222").foregroundColor(.clear) // invisible placeholder
        }
        .background(Color.red)
        .clipShape(Capsule())
    }
```

Comment: Seems a good idea. I tried that one with just "1" and using aspectRatio to 1, so the text is a perfect square, which means the result is an horizontal capsule and in the worse case, a circle, but for some reason aspectRatio does not work with Text. Any suggestion about how to make a Text a perfect square? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I also tried rotating 90 degrees Text("1"), to create a perfect square, but the actual frame is the original one.

Comment: Well, finally I found a way combining different things. I use the measure modifier with .fixedSize to get the size of Text("1"). Then I change the frame using the height in both dimensions. Later I apply your ZStack trick. 
It is working, although seems to me overcomplicated, and it is using GeometryReader, which is not ideal. If you have any suggestion let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Put it on a `ZStack` with an invisible circle symbol `Image` wich can accept font:

```
ZStack {    
    Image(systemName: "circle")
        .opacity(0)

    Text(title)
}
```